# default validations occured on jsp page loading in struts 1.3?

Tags: struts-1

I have a doubt on struts 1.x validations. I created one form and applied validations using validatorForm  and perform crud operations on that form. While applying validations on that form by default  validations are getting enabled without clicking on submit button  and edit and delete operations are not working properly which i have given in list. I configured `struts.xml` file with `validate=true` and `scope=session` attributes in action mappings. Please suggest a solution for this problem.

action mappings are:

```
<action name="RegForm" path="/reg" parameter="method" validate="true" 
            type="com.action.RegAction" scope="session" input="/jsp/reg.jsp">
            <forward name="success" path="/jsp/reg.jsp" />
            <forward name="cancel" path="/jsp/dashboard.jsp" />
        </action>
```

jsp page:

```
<bean:message key="label.form.regname" />: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <html:text property="regname" />
        <font color="red"> <html:errors property="name"/></font>
        <br />
        <br />
```

validation.xml:

```
<field property="name" depends="required,mask">
    <msg name="required" key="err.form.regname.required" />
    <msg name="mask" key="err.form.regname.invalid" />
    <var>
        <var-name>mask</var-name>
        <var-value>^[a-zA-Z \s]*$</var-value>
    </var>
</field>
```

....

Comment: Struts 1.x is EOL (END OF LIFE) so you have to upgrade your framework.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Actually I  want to perform crud operations on each and every form and i created all forms and applied validations and working properly Of course i store the data in database and displayed in same page and Now i applied edit and delete operations on every row.I want to edit the data on the list but default validations are occurred.- @RomanC

Comment: So you remove this validations and done.

Comment: Dear @RomanC sir, If I remove the validations it is working perfectly and all operations are  executed but i required validations ,without out validations user enter any type of data and that stores in database.So ,Please suggest the solution of this problem.

Comment: No, it's impossible.

Comment: can you please suggest me how to add Server side validations in struts 1.x using validator framework.I tried using  Action Form and Validator Form in struts 1.x validator framework.

Comment: issue resolved @Roman C